# Prove that $1,t-1,t^2-t,\cdots,t^{n-1}-t^{n-2}$ a basis for any polynomial $P_{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

> Prove that $1,t-1,t^2-t,\cdots,t^{n-1}-t^{n-2}$ a basis for any polynomial $P_{n-1}$ represented by $a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}$

$$
p(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}=
$$

Would be helpful I someone can give me a hint on how to rearrange the terms to show that the given set is a basis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $S=\{1, t, t^2, \dots, t^{n-1}\}$ is a bais of $P_{n-1}$.

Now consider the linear map $f\colon P_{n-1}\to P_{n-1}$ given by
$$
f(1) = 1,\ f(t) = t-1,\ f(t^2) = t^2-t,\ \dots,\ f(t^{n-1}) = t^{n-1} - t^{n-2}.
$$

The matrix of $f$ with respect to $S$ is obtained as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \ddots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \ddots & -1 \\
0  & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since this matrix is invertible as an upper triangular matrix with non-zero diagonal entries, the linear map $f$ is an automorphism.

Hence, $f(S)$ is a basis as well.

Answer (score 2):

Write their trivial linear combination: $$a_11 +a_2(t-1)+a_3(t^2-t)+\cdots +a_n(t^{n-1}-t^{n-2})=0$$

so $$(a_1-a_2)1 + (a_2-a_3)t+(a_3-a_4)t^2+\cdots+(a_{n-1}-a_n)t^{n-2}+a_nt^{n-1}=0 $$

is valid for all $t$ which means that this polynomial is actually zero polynomial, so $$a_1-a_2=a_2-a_3=...= a_{n-1}-a_{n}=a_n=0$$

so all $a_i$ are zero and thus a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to show that some set is a basis for the set of polynomials, is to show that every element of the usual basis for the set of polynomials can be written as a sum of elements of your new basis.

In this case, it is therefore sufficient to show that $1, t, t^2, ..., t^{n-1}$ can be written as sums of elements of your new basis.

As $1 = 1, t = (t-1) + 1, t^2 = (t^2-t) + (t-1) + 1, ...$, this condition is satisfied, and therefore your new set is a basis for the set of polynomials.